# How to solve Lorenz equations numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

I wrote a swift program to solve the Lorenz equations numerically with the classical Runge-Kutta method of order $4$.

I used the start coordinate $(1, 1, 1)$ and the step $h = 0.003$.

After about $45$ million steps, the solution converges to the "numerical fixpoint" $(x:  -8.48528137423224, y:  -8.48528137422238, z:  27.0000000000021$) and the game is over.

Could somebody link me another numerical method to solve the equations, which is not too difficult to implement and is better than the classical Runge-Kutta method ?

Many different suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

---

#### Code used

Here my swift code, which is easy to check:

```
import Foundation

typealias coordinata3D    = ( x: Double, y: Double, z: Double )

let sigma : Double        = 10
let r     : Double        = 28
let b     : Double        = 8/3
let dt    : Double        = 0.003
let max   : Int           = 45_000_000
let x0    : coordinata3D  = ( x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 )

func f ( p : coordinata3D ) -> coordinata3D {    
    return ( x: sigma * (p.y - p.x),             
             y: r * p.x - p.y - p.x * p.z,             
             z: p.x * p.y - b * p.z )    
}

func nextStepRungeKuttaMethod ( X : coordinata3D ) -> coordinata3D {    
    var k1: coordinata3D = f( p: X )    
    k1.x = k1.x * dt    
    k1.y = k1.y * dt    
    k1.z = k1.z * dt
    
    var k2: coordinata3D = f( p: ( x: X.x + k1.x/2,                                   
                                   y: X.y + k1.y/2,                                   
                                   z: X.z + k1.z/2 ) )
    k2.x = k2.x * dt    
    k2.y = k2.y * dt    
    k2.z = k2.z * dt
    
    var k3: coordinata3D = f( p: ( x: X.x + k2.x/2,                                   
                                   y: X.y + k2.y/2,
                                   z: X.z + k2.z/2 ) )    
    k3.x = k3.x * dt 
    k3.y = k3.y * dt    
    k3.z = k3.z * dt
    
    var k4: coordinata3D = f( p: ( x: X.x + k3.x,                                   
                                   y: X.y + k3.y,                                   
                                   z: X.z + k3.z ) )    
    k4.x = k4.x * dt    
    k4.y = k4.y * dt    
    k4.z = k4.z * dt
    
    let dtSesto : Double   = dt / 6
    
    return ( x: X.x + dtSesto * ( k1.x + 2 * ( k2.x + k3.x )  + k4.x ),             
             y: X.y + dtSesto * ( k1.y + 2 * ( k2.y + k3.y )  + k4.y ),             
             z: X.z + dtSesto * ( k1.z + 2 * ( k2.z + k3.z )  + k4.z ) )
    
}

var X : coordinata3D = x0

for _ in 1...max {    
    X = nextStepRungeKuttaMethod( X: X )    
}
Swift.print("x:  \(X.x)  y:  \(X.y)  z:  \(X.z)")

X = nextStepRungeKuttaMethod( X: X )
Swift.print("x:  \(X.x)  y:  \(X.y)  z:  \(X.z)")

X = nextStepRungeKuttaMethod( X: X )
Swift.print("x:  \(X.x)  y:  \(X.y)  z:  \(X.z)")
```

and here the result:

```
x:  -8.48528137423224  y:  -8.48528137422238  z:  27.0000000000021
x:  -8.48528137423224  y:  -8.48528137422238  z:  27.0000000000021
x:  -8.48528137423224  y:  -8.48528137422238  z:  27.0000000000021
```

#### Images of the solution

| the lorenz-attractor for `x0 = (8, 8, 8)` | detail around limit point |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Lorenz attractor] | [image: zoom to detail] |
| [original: lorenz](https://www.wohnmobilforum.de/bilderdienst/wohnmobile/lorenz_14287_d321.jpg) | [original: detail](https://www.wohnmobilforum.de/bilderdienst/wohnmobile/lorenz2_14287_590c.jpg) |

it is quite strange....

Comment: check [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method#Swift) to make sure your implementation is correct.

Comment: You know that the Lorenz-system is chaotic? So even small errors will eventually result in huge errors. You are solving in the interval $[0, 135000]$.

Comment: i think my implementation is correct and i know that the lorenz attractor is chaotic. i get the lorenz attractor with my implementation but at the end after so many million steps it goes to a numerical fixpoint.

Comment: Did you use the system parameters Lorentz considered, ${\displaystyle \sigma =10}, {\displaystyle \beta =8/3},  {\displaystyle \rho =28}$, where the system is chaotic? Then, you shouldn't be surprised by strange behavior of numerical solutions, indeed.  
And did you write a swift program, or a Swift program, as @Dando18 understood it? BTW, his link shows deprecated Swift 2, there aren't any C-style for-loops left in Swift 3.

Comment: RK4 sometimes has issues with energy preservation and over very long times can give incorrect solutions. It's good to check against other methods to see if they give the same long term behavior.

Comment: I wrote a swift3 program, which is below. I used the classical parameter sigma = 10, b = 8/3 and r = 28. i would like tu use an other metod instead runge-kutta4 but i don't know which is good for the lorenz equations.

Comment: @P.Siehr However, the attractor structure ensures that a pattern will emerge, no matter what errors occur. Therefore the problem is not in numeric errors, but in the implementation.

Comment: "which is easy to check": avoid such demeaning comments.

Comment: Is $b$ equal to $8/3$ or to $2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

This implementation has a subtle error. In the combination formula of the RK4 step, you cumulatively multiply the values of $f$ with $(dt)^2/6$ instead of the required $dt/6$. Note that the $k$ values are already `dt*f(...)`. This gives you effectively a first order method with step size $(dt)^2=9·10^{-6}$. This means that the numerical solution by this method will still follow the strange attractor, but that the numerical step might introduce perturbations that become dominant where the vector field is zero.

To examine this effect consider the linearization of a single method step at the stationary point, that is, apply the method step to the linearization of the ODE system there.

```
sigma, rho, beta = 10, 28, 8/3
z0 = rho-1
x0=y0=-(beta*z0)**0.5

M = np.array([[-sigma, sigma, 0], [rho-z0, -1, -x0], [y0, x0,-beta]])
I = np.identity(3);
def RK4_wrong(h):
    k1 = h*M
    k2 = h*M@(I+k1/2)
    k3 = h*M@(I+k2/2)
    k4 = h*M@(I+k3)
    return I+h/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)

λ,v = np.linalg.eig(RK4_wrong(0.003))
print(λ,abs(λ), np.log(λ)/9e-6)
```

The resulting matrix has

- the eigenvalues $$λ_k=[0.99987786,\, 0.99999944+9.17621049·10^{-5}j,\, 0.99999944-9.17621049·10^{-5}j]$$
- with absolute values $$|λ_k|=[0.99987786,\, 0.99999945,\, 0.99999945]$$
- or as exponents in $λ_k=e^{9·10^{-6}·l_k}$, $$l_k= [-13.57143033,\, -0.06148706+10.19579509j,\, -0.06148706-10.19579509j]$$

This shows that the stationary points are now stable. However, at larger distances from the stationary points the qualitative behavior will still be close to the one of the exact solution, so there will be a region where the inward spirals turn into outward spirals. This is exactly what you see in the plots. Once the trajectory lands in the inner region, it will converge to the stable stationary point of the discretized system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Help Lutz. After 4 years I finally know now what was the mistake !

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
I used an [*Euler* iteration which is rescaled at each step](https://cdpn.io/fpmarin/debug/LYZmOXz) to enforce the smoothness of the spatial performance.
\begin{align}
&\mbox{Write}\ \Delta\vec{r} = \vec{v}\pars{\vec{r}}\Delta t\
\mbox{as}\  \Delta\vec{r} = {\vec{v}\pars{\vec{r}} \over \verts{\vec{v}\pars{\vec{r}}}}\Delta\ell\,,\quad
\vec{v}\pars{\vec{r}} \not= \vec{0}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Delta\ell \equiv \verts{\vec{v}\pars{\vec{r}}}\Delta t}$ is a *fixed quantity*.

In this way, you enforce
$\ds{\verts{\Delta\vec{r}} = \Delta\ell}$. It means that at each step, $\ds{\Delta t}$ is changed to enforce the data smoothness ( by the way, in a picture we see $\ds{\vec{r}}$ instead of
$\ds{t}$ ). In addition, that avoids the cumbersome
Runge-Kutta.